# Is it possible to use prepared statement placeholders for LIKE?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

This fails: 
`db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column + " LIKE '?%'");`

Because the `?` is not recognized as a placeholder for a value. How should I work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the wildcard in the variable, rather than in the statement, like:

```
stmt = db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column + " LIKE ?");
stmt.setString(1, "myterm%");
```

Comment: That would only work if the code around it knew it was going to be used for a LIKE, which would be a poor design decision as it binds the variable to only those statements that use like

Answer (score 1):

Pass your value into the `CONCAT()` function:

```
db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table 
    + " WHERE " + column 
  + " LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')");
```

The advantage of doing it this way is the code making the call doesn't need to know that the parameter is being used with a LIKE, so you could use the same parameter value with other non-LIKE queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the percent sign as part of the LIKE parameter:

```
db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column + " LIKE ?");
```

I don't like the query much.  I don't think you're saving much by concatenating table and column in this way.